# Money transfer from India to Dubai

Tags: india, loans, money-transfer, international-transfer, dubai

I have to go back to India due to job loss and have to repay my bank loan in Dubai.

How can I transfer money from my savings account to my bank in Dubai?

Answer (score 1):

If the funds are in NRE account, then there is no issue. You just instruct your bank in India to transfer.

If your tax status in India is Non-Resident Indian, you should not be holding a normal Savings bank account.

Under the [liberalized remittance scheme](https://rbi.org.in/Scripts/NotificationUser.aspx?Id=10192&Mode=0) you can transfer upto 2,50,000 USD per year. You would need to instruct your bank in India to initiate a international wire transfer. The [FAQs are here](https://rbi.org.in/SCRIPTs/FAQView.aspx?Id=115)